# How to get Silverlight to access my HTML DOM

Tags: silverlight, dom

Basically I have a silverlight web App that resides within an IFrame. and that IFrame resides within a Frame of its own.  And i want to access Buttons in the dom within the outer Frame..  Here is kind of a map of how it looks.

```
-My Application
   -Frame
      -Button
      -Iframe
         -Silverlight web wrapper
            -Silverlight
```

Can I and How do i get from the silverlight App all the way back up the dom to click that dang button?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be pretty easy to do.  You can directly access the DOM via `HtmlPage.Document` object:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = HtmlPage.Document;
```

Make certain to first add a reference to the `System.Windows.Browser` namespace

[here](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/10/06/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-56-accessing-the-html-dom-from-silverlight.aspx) is more information. and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.htmldocument_members(VS.95).aspx) is the MSDN doc on HtmlDocument object.

Comment: Even though silverlight is nested within a iframe which is nested within another frame?  How do i get out to the second parent object above?

Comment: it seems that under normal circumstances, the iframe has no access to its parent's DOM, but you can call javascript methods on said parent.  so a workaround would be to create a javascript method that does the job, then call that from your silverlight. example at http://boyerblog.twistvc.com/read.php?eid=20

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post: [Accessing parent document from within nested iframes](http://boyerblog.twistvc.com/read.php?eid=20)
. I would guess that you will have to use javascript to accomplish you goal